# Python imports from Jupyter Notebook in a parallel folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, jupyter-notebook, python-3.8

I have an application structured like the following:

```
main-folder/
    __init__.py
    application.py
    modules/
        module_1/
            module_1.py
        module_2/
            module_2.py
    notebooks/
        __init__.py
        notebook_1.ipynb
        notebook_2.ipynb
```

When opening any of the notebooks and doing:

```py
from modules.module_1.module_1 import MyModule1
>>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'

from ..modules.module_1.module_1 import MyModule1
>>> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

from .. import modules
>>> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How to correctly import `modules` while running the notebook from the `notebooks` folder? Easy fix would be to put all notebooks in `main-folder` but I can't think of anything dirtier than that.

Comment: Unless the notebooks are part of the package code, move them to a different directory.

Comment: Just tried moving all application files into an `application` folder, but the problem seems to be that the code from the notebooks can't access anywhere outside the `notebook` directory — I don't want the notebooks lying in the root main-folder just like that, is there any solution to this?

Comment: notebook file may not be treated as part of module so using relative paths may not work and you may have to add `/full/path/main-folder/` to `sys.path` before `import module`

Comment: as I know relative paths works when it is used in file which is imported to other files but not when you run this file directly. Besides `notebook` file is not normal file which Python can run directly - it needs tool Jupyter for this - so it not treated as part of module.

Comment: @furas using `os.chdir()` did the trick, but your solution would have worked as well, thanks